# Android: linking radio buttons to different radio groups

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group

Hi i am new to android studio and i am creating a quiz page on my android app. However, i am having trouble with adding radio buttons to each question's radio group dynamically. Can somebody guide me on this? Below are my codes:

```
public class QuizActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ArrayList<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    ArrayList<Choice> choiceList = new ArrayList<Choice>();
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    QuestionItem item;
    List<QuestionItem> items;


    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
        context = this;
        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this);

        items = new ArrayList<QuestionItem>();
        items = fillData(items);

        listAdapter.setData(items);

        //get listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.explist_view);

        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        expListView.setDivider(null);
        for(int i=0; i < listAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
            expListView.expandGroup(i);
        }
        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
                // Doing nothing
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    public List<QuestionItem> fillData(List<QuestionItem> itemsGroup) {
        try{
            TinyDB db = new TinyDB(this);
            CacheObject co;
            co = (CacheObject)db.getObject("cache", CacheObject.class);
            questionList = co.getQuestionList();
            choiceList = co.getChoiceList();
            this.items = itemsGroup;
            Question q;
            Choice c;
            for(int i=0;i<questionList.size();i++){
                q = questionList.get(i);

                item = new QuestionItem();
                item.name = q.getQuestionContent();
                item.id = q.getQuestionID();
                for(int j=0;j<choiceList.size();j++){
                    c = choiceList.get(j);
                    if(c.getQuestionID()==q.getQuestionID()){
                        ChoiceItem child = new ChoiceItem();
                        child.name = c.getChoiceContent();
                        child.id = c.getChoiceID();
                        child.questionID = c.getQuestionID();
                        child.score = c.getChoiceScore();

                        item.choiceItems.add(child);
                    }
                }

                items.add(item);
            }

            co.setChoiceList(choiceList);
            co.setQuestionList(questionList);
            db.putObject("cache",co);

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return items;
    }

    public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        Context context;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private RadioGroup radioGroup;

        private List<QuestionItem> items;

        public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        public void setData(List<QuestionItem> items) {
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public ChoiceItem getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return items.get(groupPosition).choiceItems.get(childPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                                 boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ChildHolder childHolder;
            ChoiceItem choice = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

            if (convertView == null) {
                childHolder = new ChildHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choice_listview_row, null);

                childHolder.radio = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.choice);
                convertView.setTag(childHolder);
            } else {
                childHolder = (ChildHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            childHolder.radio.setText(choice.name);
            childHolder.radio.setId(choice.id);
            //Log.e("ChoiceID",childHolder.radio.getId()+"");

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return items.get(groupPosition).choiceItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public QuestionItem getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return items.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                                 View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            GroupHolder holder;
            QuestionItem item = getGroup(groupPosition);

            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new GroupHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_listview_row, null);

                holder.radioGroup = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question);
                holder.radioGroup.setTag(groupPosition);

                holder.content = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.questionRow);

            } else {
                holder = (GroupHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.content.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            holder.content.setText(item.name);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private static class QuestionItem {
        String name;
        int id;
        List<ChoiceItem> choiceItems = new ArrayList<ChoiceItem>();
    }

    private static class ChoiceItem {
        String name;
        int id;
        int questionID;
        int score;
    }

    private static class ChildHolder {
        RadioButton radio;
    }

    private static class GroupHolder {
        TextView content;
        RadioGroup radioGroup;
    }
}
```

EDIT: i have managed to add the buttons into the radio group but now i am facing this issue where there are additional buttons added in. Below are a screenshot and the codes i changed in the Adapter:

[emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD66j.jpg) in the view, question 1 is supposed to have only 2 choices, however other buttons are added in as i scroll down and up again.

```
   public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private List<QuestionItem> items;
    private ArrayList<RadioGroup> rgList = new ArrayList<RadioGroup>();

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void setData(List<QuestionItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public ChoiceItem getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return items.get(groupPosition).choiceItems.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ChildHolder childHolder;
        ChoiceItem choice = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            childHolder = new ChildHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choice_listview_row, parent, false);
            childHolder.radio = new RadioButton(context);

            switch(childPosition){
                case 0:
                    childHolder.radio.setId(R.id.choice1);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    childHolder.radio.setId(R.id.choice2);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    childHolder.radio.setId(R.id.choice3);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    childHolder.radio.setId(R.id.choice4);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    childHolder.radio.setId(R.id.choice5);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    childHolder.radio.setId(R.id.choice6);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    childHolder.radio.setId(R.id.choice7);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    childHolder.radio.setId(R.id.choice8);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    childHolder.radio.setId(R.id.choice9);
                    break;
                case 9:
                    childHolder.radio.setId(R.id.choice10);
                    break;
            }

            childHolder.radio.setTag(childPosition);

            if(choice.questionID == groupPosition+1) {
                childHolder.radio.setText(choice.name);
                rgList.get(groupPosition).addView(childHolder.radio);
                Log.e("testAdd",rgList.get(groupPosition).getId()+"");
            }

            convertView.setTag(childHolder);
        } else {
            childHolder = (ChildHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        childHolder.radio.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Log.e("Hello","");
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return items.get(groupPosition).choiceItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public QuestionItem getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return items.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        GroupHolder holder;
        QuestionItem item = getGroup(groupPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new GroupHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_listview_row, parent, false);
            holder.content = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.questionRow);

            holder.radioGroup = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question1);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (GroupHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //Log.e("radioGroupID", holder.radioGroup.getTag()+"");
        holder.content.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        holder.content.setText(item.name);
        switch(groupPosition){
            case 0:
                holder.radioGroup.setId(R.id.question1);
                break;
            case 1:
                holder.radioGroup.setId(R.id.question2);
                break;
            case 2:
                holder.radioGroup.setId(R.id.question3);
                break;
            case 3:
                holder.radioGroup.setId(R.id.question4);
                break;
            case 4:
                holder.radioGroup.setId(R.id.question5);
                break;
            case 5:
                holder.radioGroup.setId(R.id.question6);
                break;
            case 6:
                holder.radioGroup.setId(R.id.question7);
                break;
            case 7:
                holder.radioGroup.setId(R.id.question8);
                break;
            case 8:
                holder.radioGroup.setId(R.id.question9);
                break;
            case 9:
                holder.radioGroup.setId(R.id.question10);
                break;
        }
        holder.radioGroup.setTag(groupPosition);

        if (!rgList.contains(holder.radioGroup.getTag(groupPosition))) {
            rgList.add(holder.radioGroup);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return true;
    }
}

private static class QuestionItem {
    String name;
    int id;
    List<ChoiceItem> choiceItems = new ArrayList<ChoiceItem>();
}

private static class ChoiceItem {
    String name;
    int id;
    int questionID;
    int score;
}

private static class ChildHolder {
    RadioButton radio;
}

private static class GroupHolder {
    TextView content;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
}
```

}